# Can't bundle sass and handlebars - webpack config

Tags: javascript, webpack, handlebars.js

I'm running a very small application in node, and I'm using `webpack` to bundle my js with handlebars, meanwhile I was using `gulp` to proccess my sass file to css.

When I removed the handlebars code from the main html file and put it in a .hbs file, to require from mainjs and them call only a single js file in the html, my css seems not to reach the .hbs html code, so I tried to bundle sass file alltogheter with webpack as well, but then I got errors in main js file that can't read the css.

This is my webpack.config.js

```
  var path = require("path");

  module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    entry: {
      js: "./public/javascripts/main.js",
      css: "./public/sass/style.scss"
    },
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./public/javascripts"),
      filename: '[name].js',
      publicPath: "./public/javascripts"
    },
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        javascripts: path.join(__dirname, "./public/javascripts")
      }
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        { test: /\.hbs$/, loader: "@icetee/handlebars-loader" },
        { test: /\.(s*)css$/,
          use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']}
      ]
    }
  };
```

this is my main.js file

```
    // your code

    var celebritiesTemplate = require("./celebritiesTemplate.hbs");

    var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ourRequest.open('GET', '../fazenda.json');
    ourRequest.onload = function() {
      if (ourRequest.status >= 200 && ourRequest.status < 400) {
        var data = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
        createHTML(data);
      } else {
        console.log("We connected to the server, but it returned an error.");
      }
    };

    ourRequest.onerror = function() {
      console.log("Connection error");
    };

    ourRequest.send();

    function createHTML(petsData) {
      var rankingContainer = document.getElementById("ranking");
      rankingContainer.innerHTML = celebritiesTemplate(petsData);
    }
```

and my .hbs file

```
        {{#each data}}

        <div class="celebrityStats" class="row">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="{{picture}}" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="row-number">1</div>
            <div class="specifics">
                <div class="row-title"> {{name}} </div>
                <div class="row-description"> {{decription}} </div>
            </div>

            <div class="ratings">
                <div class="likes">
                    <div class="head"></div>
                    <div class="content"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="unlikes">
                    <div class="head"></div>
                    <div class="content"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        {{/each}}
```

this is my html file importing the bundled js that carries the handlebars file

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <title>R7 FrontEnd Test</title>
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      </head>
      <body>
          <!-- let's code :D -->

        <div class="container">

          <div class="box">
            <div class="box-head">
              <span class="logo">
                <img src="./assets/a-fazenda-logo.png" alt="">
              </span>
              <span class="title">
                <h1>RANKING</h1>
              </span>
            </div>

            <div id="ranking" class="main-box">


            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

        <script src="./javascripts/js.js"></script>
    </html>
```

I'm importing the .css that gulp generates from the main html, but it just don't reach the .hbs block of code, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please show the css code and how it is rendered in the browser. When you say you are importing the `css`, how are you doing it ? If the css is not applied, then looks like the issue is in selectors not applied correctly or getting over-ridden or the css is not inserted into your html file properly. The good starting point is to see the browser developer tools and see why the rules are not getting applied.

Comment: I'm importing as `<link href`, it is loading in the page, but can't reach the block of hbs code, whatever comes before is working correctly, even the handlebars is loading my data correctly